# No scrollbars appear when adding a custom view via addSubview to NSScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, nsview, custom-view, nsscrollview

I dynamically want to add a custom `NSView` as a content of a `NSScrollView` via code in runtime.
So I added a `NSScrollView` to my `NSWindow`, created an outlet to this `NSScrollView` and add my custom view.

```
@IBOutlet var myScrollView: NSView!
@IBOutlet var myCustomView: NSView!

myScrollView.addSubview(myCustomView)
```

This works fine (the content of myCustomView is shown in the `NSScrollView`) but the NSScrollView scrollbars are disabled and the content (that is larger than the `NSScrollView`) cannot be scrolled.

Is there something I am missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add scrollable content to a `NSScrollView` you should set `documentView` and not via `addSubview(_:)`

```
let myView = MyView(frame: <somerect>)
scrollView.documentView = myView
```

If scrolling is still not working you may need to specify `contentSize`

Docs for [NSScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscrollview)